# Parts Of Object Hidden, Cannot Be Sculpted

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, sculpting, masking

When I enter Sculpting mode, I found some vertices cannot not be sculpted.

[image]

[image]

I switch to edit mode and I found these vertices are hidden (?not sure).[image]

I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide these vertices. But when I switch back to sculpting mode, these vertices still cannot be sculpted.

[image]

Switch back to edit mode and this part is still hidden. (like fig.3)

How can I make these vertices available for sculpting?

What kind of function make this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recently happened to me and I believe this is a glitch. When I switch to tab mode I tried to reveal hidden <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>  the vertices. When I switch back to sculpting mode, I can't sculpt it.

Again, I believe this is a glitch. I tried to copy the mesh to 2.83 version, unhide the vertices, and copy it back to 2.9 version and it worked.
Edit: after that, whenever I add a mask the it will be invisible. I think it's a bug

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work I use 2.83 to fix mesh!